# using h2 db with data.sql, 500 error in post & delete

Tags: spring-boot, h2, crud

I made crud with Spring Boot. If you test using the swagger without creating a data.sql file, all the api work well without any problems. But, if I add data to h2 db with a data.sql file, 500 errors will occur in post and delete (Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC".USERS (ID)). Schema generation is well done in h2 db. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I think you should check your data.sql . Some ids might be same.